# Can't find scrrpt class

Tags: koma-script

I am a COMPLETE novice to latex.

I installed Mactex on my Mac, and when I open Texlive it says I have KOMA installed.

Yet when I try to compile with `\documentclass{scrrpt}` it won't compile and says `scrrpt.cls, not found`.

Apologies, I am VERY new to this, any help very welcome!

Comment: I am using TExpad

Comment: That's because there is no `scrrpt` KOMA-script class. You're probably referring to `scr­reprt`.

Comment: My advice, read some introductory material first: `texdoc dickimaw-novice`.

Answer (score 4):

The name of the class you are trying to use is called `scrreprt` and *not* `scrrpt`

A minimal example would be:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}
An MWE
\end{document}
```

I suggest you open a terminal, type in `texdoc scrguien` or if you are German `texdoc scrguide`. The gentlemen Kohm and Morawski made a big effort to provide a good and detailed documentation. You will find everything you need in this document.